# Why I shouldn't set data from computed?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, eslint

Using vuex, I receive an object, lets suppose

```
user: {name: 'test'}
```

And in app.vue I use this.$store.getters.user

```
computed: {
   user: function() {
       let user = this.$store.getters.user
       return user
   }
}
```

While setting also data object 'this.name'

```
data() {
   return {
      name: ''
   }
}

computed: {
   user: function() {
       let user = this.$store.getters.user
       this.name = user.name
       return user
   } 
}
```

But in the lint I get this error 'unexpected side effect in computed property', (the data 'name' should be used as a v-model, to be used as a update API parameter).
I know it can be ignored if you know what you're doing, and that it is triggered for setting data from computed, but why it triggers this error? and how to workaround it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't set value in **computed**. if you need to get name of computed user you must be create new computed:

```
   user: function() {
       let user = this.$store.getters.user
       return user
   },
   name: function() {
       if(this.user.name!=undefined) return this.user.name
       return ''
   },
```

and remove name from `data`

but if you realy need to set name you can `watch` user and set `name`

```
watch: {
   user(newVal) {
      if(newVal.name!=undefined) this.name = newVal.name
   }
}
```

Comment: the main concern is that without setter you cannot use computed as a v-model. I need it as a v-model with the first value of the computed, then it can be changed to anything

Comment: @NataJdaCOliveira So use the second solution, `watch`

Comment: I guess that's the correct way, thanks! But why it is considered a bad practice to do it directly? Computed is similar to watch in some aspects, and also (IIRC) it updates when data is changed, so it should work equally, right?

Comment: Very simple. Because it's called. computed

Answer (score 1):

Vue has both computed getters and [setters](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter). If you define a computed property as you did above it is only a getter. A getter is meant to only "get" a value and it should be a ["pure" function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) with no [side effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)) so that it is easier to read, debug and test.

From the [docs](https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/no-side-effects-in-computed-properties.html) for the rule that triggered the linting error on your code:

> It is considered a very bad practice to introduce side effects inside
> computed properties. It makes the code not predictable and hard to
> understand.

In your case you might want to use a computed setter for either the `user` or the `name` values so that you can use them as `v-model`s. You could, for example, do:

```
computed: {
  user: function () {
    return this.$store.getters.user;
  },
  user: {
    // getter
    get: function () {
      return this.user.name;
    },
    // setter
    set: function (newValue) {
      this.$store.commit('setUserName', newValue);
    }
  }
}
```